# Why is FlexeLint giving errors and warnings on C++11 constructs?

Tags: c++11, pc-lint

I'm working with FlexeLint 9.00L and am having a problem with it recognizing my C++11 code as proper.
The command I'm using is:
*flint -os[outputFile] -u lint_options.lnt Bus.cpp*
In my lint_options.lnt file I have (amongst other options) **-A(C++11)**
The output I'm getting in my class declaration Bus.h states
*Bus.h 156 Error 1001: Scope 'chrono' must be a struct or class name*

`void SendContinuousMsg (std::string message, std::chrono::milliseconds messageGap`

It's also not catching the fact that std::thread::joinable() does not throw an exception in C++11 ([std::thread::joinable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable)) giving me a warning (1551) that it may throw an exception.

Am I doing something wrong in my lint_options.lnt file that is causing Flexelint to ignore the C++11 code?

Any help would be appreciated.